# Transfer audio book from iPad to Mac

Tags: itunes

I bought an audio book on my iTunes account, using my iPad. Now I can't transfer it to my macbook. From my macbook, it does not appear in my purchases.

Is there anyway to transfer it?

Answer (score 1):

Before you transfer your purchases, make sure that your MacBook is authorized with the same Apple ID account you used to make the purchases. 
And for audio books, only one download is normally allowed per purchase. You can find the answer in Apple support center.

To transfer purchases from your device to a computer:

1. Connect your device to the computer. Wait for its icon to appear in iTunes.
2. Go to File > Devices.
3. If you're using iTunes for Windows and can't see the menu bar, learn how to turn on iTunes menus in Windows.
4. Choose Transfer Purchases from [device name].

Comment: Can you add some details/links about the Apple Support article mentioned and "how to turn on iTunes menus in Windows"?

Comment: Both machines use the same account. It is the one download per purchase that answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: There is a problem with my account, it seems I have two accounts with the same same but one is unregistered and I can't login to it. Unfortunately it is the one my question was asked with. I can't seem to accept your answer. I apologize for this. I (at least) upvoted your answer.